# how does one secure one's key when writing an oracle?

Tags: private-key, oracles

I'm looking to write an oracle that will interact with the blockchain in the following way.

- Client submit a withdrawal request on the contract
- The Oracle will pick up that request, check the balance of client on an external app and then approve the request on the chain.
- The contract will then release funds to the client when approved.

So if the keys of the oracle gets lost, a malicious actor can submit a withdrawal request for a huge amount of money and then use the oracle's key to approve that particular request.

I'm wondering how oracles are protecting their keys, being constantly connected to the net and also needing maintainence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are practical ways to go about this, that experienced node operators tend to follow:

- best practice is to first of all limit the access of the "hot" (private) key as much as possible,
- make it easy and secure for admins to rotate it (i.e easily replace the wallet keys for the oracle if a breach occurs. Commonly, the smart contract that the oracle interacts with whitelist the oracle,so updating the whitelist is part of the 'rotation' process)
- For storing it, the recommended approach is to store it ***encrypted*** in the filesystem
- only decrypt it ***in-memory***, when needed.

If you're using cloud providers then it may be worth looking at tools they offer -- GCP and AWS offer secret manager services that can be leveraged.

Comment: can you explain more about key rotation? as in... don't you need the right key for the right contract?

Comment: @zcaudate - have updated the point on rotation (it's different from rotation policies for symmetric keys).

Comment: got it. thanks for your help.

Comment: so the keys are not kept but regenerated? ie. you don't want to rotate it back to an old key may have already been compromised.

Comment: Exactly -- its important to make key replacement quick and effective because this is important for security, and you limit the downside of a private key being breached.   If breached then any ETH and tokens associated with that account will likely get taken but hopefully that will be the worst of it.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you just have different oracle designs.  Some of them like Chainlink do have some keys that you need to trust and it's probably similar to most exchange security.  Other oracle designs, e.g. Tellor, Witnet, API3, don't have quite the centralization so rather than trust one set of keys, you have a series of incentive mechanisms in a smart contract.

A great (simple) example is that you allow anyone to be your oracle, but they have to stake $1M.  Then after the result is posted on chain, you can all check it and vote whether to accept the result or slash the oracle.  Now there are no keys at all you need to secure.